# how to change the Wordpress post thunmbnails size in different devices display

Tags: wordpress, post

I have issues to make thunmbnails size on different devices display.
on Mobile size display, it still shows large thunmbnials size, it does not auto adjust image size to fit mobile devices. please advise.
Please check the attached img. thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating speicifc image sizes for your uploaded image and then you srcset's to trigger which image is shown at what size.

For the image sizes, use the following in your functions.php:

```
add_image_size('mobile', 480, '', false);
```

This would create the 'mobile' size at 480px in width and the correct ratio'd height depending on the image.

Once you've created this, you will be able to call this version of the image. If you need any further help, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Add mobile detect plugin and add below condition so it will work for you.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/mobble/

You can use diffrent different size based on condition.

```
<?php
   if (is_mobile()) {
   the_post_thumbnail('medium');
   } else {
   the_post_thumbnail('large');
} ?>
```